# Use SSH keys on several machines

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-keys

So I try this for my first machine lets name it M1

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

leaving the file name as default, and then copy the public keys to the server (S1):

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_ras.pub hostamne@172.16.254.1:~ssh/authorized_keys
```

So far so good, I'm able to log in to the server with no problems

Then I do the same

```
ssh-keygen -b 4096
```

for the 2nd machine (M2) having the id_ras name changed to id_ras2. Then copy the public key to the server S1

```
scp ~/.ssh/id_ras2.pub hostamne@172.16.254.1:~ssh/authorized_keys
```

After I disable password authentication it lock me out form the server from both machines (M1 and M2).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details what machines you have and from where to where you want to connect using `ssh`. It is not clear what exactly you did for the second machine. Please make clear what commands you executed on which machine. Renaming a key file might make it unusable if `ssh` expects a specific name.

Answer (score 2):

`scp` is `cp` over `ssh`. Your second call overwrites the `authorized_keys` file from the first one.

Simply use `ssh-copy-id`, which is a dedicated tool for this task:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ras2.pub user@10.0.0.1
```